# What does "Not that that’s any shade on what you do" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I am wondering what "Not that
that’s any shade on what you do" means in the following sentences:

> ‘Well,’ I say. ‘Funny you should say that, but I did actually do a
> try-out for the show.’
>
> ‘You did?’ Hannah asks. ‘For *Survive the Night*?’
>
> ‘Yeah.’ Ah, Christ. Why did I say anything? *Stupid Johnno, always
> shooting my mouth off.* Jesus, it’s humiliating.
>
> ‘Yeah, well, they did a screen test, with the two of us, and—’
>
> ‘And Johnno decided he wasn’t up for any of that crap, didn’t you?’
> Will says. It’s good of him to try to save my blushes. But there’s no
> point in lying now, I might as well say it. ‘He’s being a good mate,’
> I say. ‘Truth is I was shit at it. They basically told me I didn’t
> work on screen. Not like our boy here—’ I lean over and muss up Will’s
> hair, and he ducks away, laughing. ‘I mean, he’s right. It wasn’t for
> me anyway. Couldn’t stand any of that make-up they slap on you, the
> clothes they make you wear. **Not that that’s any shade on what you
> do**, mate.’
>
> ‘No offence taken,’ Will says, putting up his hands. He’s a natural on
> screen. He has this ability to be whoever people want him to be. When
> he’s on the programme I notice he drops his ‘h’s’, sounds a bit more
> like ‘one of the people’. But when he’s with posh, public
> school-educated blokes, blokes who came from the better versions of
> the sort of school we both went to, he’s one of them – 100 per cent.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 15

The speakers are at the rehearsal dinner the day before the wedding between Jules and Will who is the celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*. Johnno is the best man and high school friends with Will.

In this part, I wonder what Johnno means.

I am guessing that "shade" here has the same meaning as "[throw shade](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/throw-shade)", meaning that Johnno is disrespectful of Will's career, but I am still not sure about its exact meaning, so I just wanted to ask you.

Comment: Yes, you got it so why the question??

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of this writer's use of certain colloquialisms. Assuming the text is somewhat "autobiographical", she wouldn't necessarily have good first-hand experience of all the "quaint" turns of phrase she puts into the mouths of her characters. And this *particular* usage looks to me like a malapropism for *It's [not a **patch** on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20not%20a%20patch%20on#:~:text=British%2C%20informal,a%20patch%20on%20his%20predecessor.) what you do*. Or maybe "patch" occurs here as a dialectal (Irish?) alternative, I dunno.

Comment: (There a lot of overlap between ***shade, swatch, patch*** in the literal context of fabrics and haberdashery. And the "patch" version [*isn't* just a British usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+a+shade+on%2Cnot+a+patch+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3))

Comment: Hmm. I can't say this author interests me at all (to be honest, the book sounds insufferably dull), but having read @FumbleFingers link, I agree. The phrase *throw shade* means to insult a person or what they do; her not liking the job isn't throwing shade.

Comment: Dear everyone, thank you very much for the explanations. I was actually confused because I found the meaning of "throw shade" but couldn't find the meaning of "a shade on", so I wondered if they are two entirely different expressions and I am mixing them together. So "a shade on" means to insult someone about what they do! I sincerely appreciate your help. :)